# Need some help regarding webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, session, asmx

I started learning webservices, I was going smoothly upto [this topic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service). If you can see here is code in click event to create `proxy` and storing 'Cookie' there:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    localhost.MyDemo MyService;

    // try to get the proxy from Session state
    MyService = Session["MyService"] as localhost.MyDemo;

    if (MyService == null)
    {
        // create the proxy
        MyService = new localhost.MyDemo();

        // create a container for the SessionID cookie
        MyService.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        // store it in Session for next usage
        Session["MyService"] = MyService;
    }

    // call the Web Service function
    Label1.Text += MyService.HelloWorld() + "<br />";
}
```

I am confused at line `MyService = Session["MyService"] as localhost.MyDemo;`.

As much as I know `as` is used for casting, I guess here it's doing the same, but

**Question 1:** as `Session` and `localhost.MyDemo` are two different object so how cast is possible?

**Question 2:** Is `as` is not doing casting here then what that line means?

**Question 3:** Why there was was need to cast ?

**Question 4:** what the value `Session["MyService"]` will have ?

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: This text will help you understand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: You have found an old tutorial on ASMX web services. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Yeah @JohnSaunders. I just thought that `WCF` will be easier after learning 'Web Services'. Thanks for great suggestion.

Comment: Actually, WCF has replaced ASMX web services as of 2006.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: should I go for WCF directly?

Comment: Yes. There is no reason to learn ASMX web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not cast `Session` to `localhost.MyDemo` but `Session["MyService"]`. `Session["MyService"]` returns an object that you need to cast to the target type. Using `[...]` calls the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in this case.
2. `as` does a cast in a friendly manner. It tries to perform the cast, but does not complain if the cast is invalid. If it cannot do the cast, it assigns `null`. Hence the check against null in the next line.
3. There was a need to cast as you can store any `object` in Session memory. In order to use the specific methods or properties of MyService, you need to cast the `object` that is returned by the indexer to an instance of `MyService`.
4. `Session["MyService"]` will be set to an instance of `MyService` once you assign it.

For a detailed overview of the HttpSessionState class (the type of the "Session" object), see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For the indexer property that you use to access variables in Session memory, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dhkksh8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: as Session and localhost.MyDemo are two different object so how cast is possible?
Session is a collection that contain objects of any type.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Question 2: Is as is not doing casting here then what that line means?
It is casting

Question 3: Why there was was need to cast ?
In this case, I can see no need as the casted value is never used except to compare to null.

Question 4: what the value Session["MyService"] will have ?
It looks like a cached reference to a web service client.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

`Session` and `localhost.MyDemo` are different but you're not using `Session`, you're looking at the object stored in `Session["MyService"]`

**Question 2**

As is like a cast however it returns null if the object is not of the particular type. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx).

**Question 3**

Objects stored in `Session["MyService"]` are objects, the as is required so it's strongly typed.

**Question 4**

`Session["MyService"]` will have whatever object was placed there - in this case

```
MyService = new localhost.MyDemo();
Session["MyService"] = MyService;
```

Personally I don't really like the code you're showing - I see no reason to store the WS reference in session (why not use a variable somewhere). `MyService` is a local variable and so should start with a lower case m and the cookie container does not appear to be needed (often only used with WebServices where you need to authenticate and hold a session).